# How to stack several column into one column but keep a column as it is in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack

Let say I have this dataframe

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p | q |
| 1 |  | q |
| 2 | p |  |
| 2 | p | q |

and I want to stack column B and C into one column (let say column `D`), But keep column `A` as it is. How to get this?

Here the expected output I want

| A | D |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | p |
| 1 | q |
| 1 | q |
| 2 | p |
| 2 | p |
| 2 | q |

Note: As far as I know, to stack column `B` and `C` into column `D` I can use this code:

```
df_temp = df[['B', 'C']]
df_temp = df_temp.stack().reset_index(name='D')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with column `A`:

```
df_temp = (df.set_index('A')[['B','C']]
              .stack()
              .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
              .reset_index(name='D'))
print (df_temp)
   A  D
0  1  p
1  1  q
2  1  q
3  2  p
4  2  p
5  2  q
```

Or:

```
df_temp = (df.melt(id_vars='A',value_vars=['B','C'], value_name='D')
             .drop('variable', axis=1)
             .dropna(subset=['D'])
             .sort_values('A', ignore_index=False))
print (df_temp)
   A  D
0  1  p
4  1  q
5  1  q
2  2  p
3  2  p
7  2  q
```